# How to change a shape made in photoshop to aftereffects shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-after-effects

I have imported a logo made in photoshop tp aftereffects and now I need to animate the borders of the shape and create trim path animation. How do I do that?

Comment: better go with Illustrator instead of photoshop since even though you use vector shapes in photoshop. it still raster! so to avoid it make logo in illustrator and then use it as footage and then create outlines from AI file and all of the shape will converted to native after effect layers :)

Answer (score 1):

As Design Phoenix mentioned, it'd be better to start creating your vector objects inside a vector software like Illustrator. However this's what you can do:

1. Save your .psd file and open it in AE as a composition

[image]

2. AE will import those as raster layers with vector masks

[image]

3. Create a new Shape Layer and start drawing a random shape. A `Path` in Contents will be created. Select your `Mask Path`, copy it and paste to `Path` of the shape layer

[image]

4. So when you have your shape layers, you can animate your properties

[image]

Comment: yeah damn this is what i usually do to copy one shape path to another but never thought this will work for PSD To. it's great though. btw i was looking for your gmail but seems google don't have it except your tweeter :) so can i have your email? i needed some sort of html panel help. i took help of well known Davide barranca but he is kinda very busy :) thanks!

Comment: my email is in my profile

Comment: If this answers your question please don't forget to accept the answer so that others could see it as a correct one. Thanks!